# Get Laravel 'public' path for javascript file

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I'm unsure how I can get something equivalent to: path('public') to work in a Javascript file?

I basically just need the path to the public folder for displaying some images from my JS file.

Comment: I always just do /public and it works. I'm not sure if there's a more modular way to do it. Sorry that I'm not more help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could opt to create a variable in JavaScripts global namespace in the head of your document and use PHP to echo out the public path.

```
<head>
    <script>
        var public_path = '{{ path('public') }}';
    </script>

...
```